# How to convince a program that my windows 10 is a korean operating system?

Tags: windows-10, language

I can't believe that a program would check to make sure you are korean in order to use a Korean program. it won't even let me install. All I want to do is practice typing in a foreign language. The program is free, but no, not if you have a US version of windows.

are there a reasonable number of registry keys i could switch to pretend to have a korean version of windows? or should I just download a virtual machine and run the OS that way..

Comment: I ran into a similar situation once. Go to Control Panel > Region and Language. There are two places you want to change it to Korea. On the Location Tab, change that location. And also the Administrative Tab, change the System Locale. Then reboot. Not guaranteeing it'll work in your situation, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comment, it appears switching system locale is enough. Thanks for the help